# Creating a lottery ticket with random different numbers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

im trying to create a lottery ticket generator where i have 5 numbers (from 1 to 50) and 2 other numbers (from 1 to 12) called stars. The five numbers cant be the same and the 2 stars cant be the same too (but can be equal to the numbers). I have to make the code in c# and put in a cshtml page with a ViewBag.
My output somehow is giving me this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8C8s.png)

My c# code is:

```
Random random = new Random();
            int number = random.Next();
                int[] numbers = new int[5];
            int[] stars = new int[2];
            bool repeated = false;
            int newnumber = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                repeated = false;
                while (repeated == true)
                {
                    newnumber = random.Next(1, 50);
                    repeated = numbers.Contains(newnumber);
                }

                numbers[i] = newnumber;

            }
            ViewBag.numbers = numbers;

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                repeated = false;
                while (repeated == true)
                {
                    newnumber = random.Next(1, 12);
                    repeated = stars.Contains(newnumber);
                }
                stars[i] = newnumber;
            }
            ViewBag.stars = stars;

         
            return View("MyView");
```

Then i put this in cshtml so it appear in my website:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 400px; height: 125px; margin: auto">
            <div class="bg-light">
                <h3 style="text-align:center">Lottery</h3>
                <p style="text-align:center">Winning numbers!</p>
               
                <p style="text-align:center">
                    Nº:@for (int i=0; i <5;i++)
                {
                    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.numbers[i]+";")
                }
                |
                    <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>:@for (int i=0; i <2;i++)
                {
                    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.stars[i]+";")
                }
                </p>           
                </div>
        </div>
```

Can you guys help me? I really dont know where is the mistake that makes the lottery ticket have just zeros.

Thank you.

Comment: You assign `repeated == false` so it would never go into the while loop. Change the code to `do while` it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
repeated = false;
while (repeated == true)
```

It will always skip `while`.

Comment: I didnt understand, what i need to do? Sorry for being so dumb but im just starting to learn code.

Comment: You should probably use this:

`do { /* set repeated to true if repetition is needed else to false */} while (repeated == true);`

Comment: Either switch to do/while or just initialize `repeated` with true instead of false.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Its good now.

Answer (score 0):

You assign repeated == false so it would never go into the while loop. Change the code to do while it should work for you.

```
 do
                {
                     //Create random number
                     //Check whether it's repeated
                     newnumber = random.Next(1, 12);
                     repeated = stars.Contains(newnumber);
                }while (repeated == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two typical methods to create unique random `k` numbers from `n`:

**1.** Create all `n` numbers, *shuffle* and then take `k` of them (this method is efficient when `k ~ n`):

```
// Simplest, Fisher-Yates algorithm is faster
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle
int[] numbers = Enumerable
  .Range(1, n)
  .OrderBy(item => random.NextDouble())
  .Take(k)
  .ToArray();
```

**2.** Generare `k` random numbers while testing for being unique (do it when `k << n`):

```
HashSet<int> data = new HashSet<int>();

while (data.Count < k)
  data.Add(random.Next(1, n + 1));

numbers = data.ToArray();
```

In your case we can extract the method:

```
private static Random s_Random = new Random();

private static int[] Generate(int count, int total) => Enumerable
  .Range(1, total)
  .OrderBy(_ => s_Random.NextDouble())
  .Take(count)
  .ToArray();
```

Then you can just call the routine:

```
ViewBag.numbers = Generate(5, 50);
ViewBag.stars = Generate(2, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regenerating numbers if there are repetitions is not very efficient. Try this:

```
var random = new Random();
var allNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 50);
var stars = allNumbers
    .OrderBy(x => random.Next())
    .Take(2)
    .ToArray();
var numbers = allNumbers
    .Except(stars)
    .OrderBy(x => random.Next())
    .Take(5);
```